# How to get redirect status in puppeteer?

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

I'm trying write Jest test using puppeteer

```js
describe('Downloads', () => {
    it(`should refirect to download page for ios`, async () => {
        await page.setUserAgent('exotic');
        let response = await page.goto(`http://localhost:8888/downloads`, {waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
        let url = page.url();
        expect(response.status()).toBe(303);
        expect(url).toBe(`http://localhost:8888/downloads/ios`);
    });
});
```

But response status is `200` because `goto` return response for `http://localhost:8888/downloads/ios`

How to get redirect status code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`request.redirectChain()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#requestredirectchain) for this. It returns an array with all requests. You can then access the first request (and response) like this:

```js
const response = await page.goto('...');

const chain = response.request().redirectChain();
const redirectRequest = chain[0];
const redirectResponse = await redirectRequest.response();

expect(redirectResponse.status()).toBe(303);
expect(redirectResponse.url()).toBe('...');
```